# Problem solving - Coding Interview Question?

Tags: python, matlab, vector, indexing

So I came along this mock interview question, I have to find a solution to this problem without using functions repelem or repmat. 
Only 3 lines of code are allowed with the format: (only one  = operator per line)
*p=... , q1=.... , q2=....,*

So far I only got a solution using repelem, but when I try to change my code I always have to use more lines of code when indexing. Very thankful for any hints you got for me :)

```
p=[4 2 5 3 1]

q1 = repelem((1:length(p)),p)
q2 = repelem(p,p)
```

Here is the question, if anyone wants to try by himself (designed for MATLAB, but can be done anywhere)

Let p be a vector with k different positive integer elements and s=sum(p). Two vectors q1 and q2 shall be determined such that:

• q1 is a vector of length s. The first p(1) elements of q1 are equal to 1, the next p(2) elements are equal to 2, . . . , the last p(k) elements are equal to k.

• q2 is a vector of length s. The first p(1) elements of q2 are equal to p(1), the next p(2) elements are equal to p(2), . . . , the last p(k) elements are equal to p(k).

Comment: Example:
p=[4 2 5 3 1] ⇒ q1=[1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5],
q2=[4 4 4 4 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 1]

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: I would change the title of the question. As it is right now, no one who is looking to solve the same problem will be able to find the solution.

Comment: Following Paolo’s comment, a more descriptive title could be: _Run-length decoding without using ‘repelem’_. Also, include the example in the question text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in **Matlab**.

Hints:

- Use [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (or [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)) and [`nonzeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html) to build `q1`.
- `q2` is easily obtained from `p` and `q1`.

Code (give it a try yourself first!):

> `p = [4 2 5 3 1]; % example input`
> `q1 = nonzeros(((1:max(p)).'<=p).*(1:numel(p))).';`
> `q2 = p(q1);`

Answer (score 1):

Typing this from a phone so not sure if the syntax is correct.

Using list comprehension we can flatten a list of lists, and using [x]*y we can create a list that repeats x y times.

```
q1 = [e for l in [[i+1]*px for i,px in enumerate(p)] for e in l]
```

Im sure q2 is similar?